# SpEL @ConditionalOnProperty string property empty or nulll

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-el

I am currently having trouble with my dataSource bean creation on condition of String property from my applications.yaml file.

Ideally, I would only like to create the dataSource bean only if the url is set in my application.yaml file. Shouldn't create the bean if its not present (empty or null). I know this condition checks on boolean but is there anyway to check if the string property is empty or null?

DatabaseConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Value("${database.url:}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${database.username:}")
    private String databaseUsername;

    @Value("${database.password:}")
    private String databasePassword;

    protected static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver";


    /**
     * Configures and returns a datasource. Optional
     *
     * @return A datasource.
     */
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "database.url")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(testDatabaseUrl)
            .username(testDatabaseUsername)
            .password(testDatabasePassword)
            .build();
    }
}
```

application.yml (This field will be optional)

```
database:
  url: http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` already has a `matchIfMissing` parameter to control what happens when the property is not present. Are you trying to say that the empty string value is a synonym for not-present in your code?

Answer (score 29):

You could use `@ConditionalOnExpression` with a [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) expression as value:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("!T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).isEmpty('${database.url:}')")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // snip
}
```

For better readability and reusability you could turn this into an annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ConditionalOnExpression("!T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).isEmpty('${database.url:}')")
public @interface ConditionalOnDatabaseUrl {
}

@ConditionalOnDatabaseUrl
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // snip
}
```

Comment: May I know why we need generic type over there?
T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils)

Comment: @Hong the `T(..)` is to reference types and has nothing to do with generics. I assume you were thinking of `<T>`. Here's the SpEL reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types

Answer (score 19):

I'm having the same issue. As I undestood, you'r looking for "property exists and not empty" condition. This condition doesn't come out of the box, therefore some coding required. Solution using `org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional` works for me:

1. Create `ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty` annotation and accompanied `OnPropertyNotEmptyCondition` class as follows:

   ```
    // ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty.java

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
    import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;
    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    import java.util.Map;

    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Conditional(ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty.OnPropertyNotEmptyCondition.class)
    public @interface ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty {
        String value();

        class OnPropertyNotEmptyCondition implements Condition {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
                Map<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty.class.getName());
                if (attrs == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                String propertyName = (String) attrs.get("value");
                String val = context.getEnvironment().getProperty(propertyName);
                return val != null && !val.trim().isEmpty();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Annotate your bean with `ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty`, like:

   ```
    @ConditionalOnPropertyNotEmpty("database.url")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() { ... }
   ```

--

Alternatively, you can either set detabase.url to false explicitly (e.g. `detabase.url: false`) or do not define `detabase.url` at all in your config. Then, `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "database.url")` will work for you as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The main answer above is correct, but since the `isEmpty` is deprecated, if you (likely) have [apache commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) loaded, you can use the `isNotEmpty` and simplify the condition

```
@ConditionalOnExpression(
    "T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isNotEmpty('${database.url:}')"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try more generic purpose annotation which is standard for the Spring Core:
`org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional`.

In the context objects for your callback you can get all the information you need: `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition`

Also you can consider using Profiles.