# How to make spring mutually exclusive beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using an interface with two bean implementations.
One implementation has a conditional.

I want them to be mutually exclusive, resulting in a single bean implementing interface.

Tried the following that results in missing bean:

```
interface BaseService {}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(...)
class ConditionalService implements BaseService{}

class FallbackService implements BaseService {}

@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public BaseService fallbackService() {
        return new FallbackService();
    }
}
```

Rejected github issue and sample repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24227

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it would help if you specified what kind of parameters you had in your `@ConditionalOnProperty`. It might also be worth taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56775226/7096763) to a similar question.

Comment: @MikaelF in my test case, `@ConditionalOnProperty` will fail, so the bean should not be created, and fallback should be used. End result was no bean was created.

Comment: Looking at your repo, there’s no `@ConditionalOnProperty`, as the main implementation is defined with a `@ConditionalOnBean`. The Spring Boot people showed you why this doesn’t work. The `@Conditional...` annotations are meant to be used on autoconfiguration classes. Are you looking for help setting one of those up?

Comment: @MikaelF Yes, please provide an example using auto-configuration

Answer (score 1):

In the linked Github issue, the people from Spring Boot already explained why your initial approach wasn't working, so I won't go into that.

Spring Boot doesn't have a `@ConditionOnMissingProperty` annotation, but you can emulate one using `@ConditonalOnExpression`, assuming you have something like `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myproperty", havingValue = "myvalue")`

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnExpression("'${myproperty}' != 'myvalue'")
    BaseService fallbackService() {
        return new FallbackService();
    }
```

Comment: the downside of this approach is code maintenance due to duplicate property